# How to let super.property as default value on a constructor parameter?

Tags: kotlin

For interface:

```
interface Some {
    val p1: String get() = "p1"
    val p2: String get() = "p2"
}
```

For class:

```
class SomeImpl(
override val p1: String = super.p1
override val p2: String = super.p2
) : Some
```

Its wrong, a compile error occurs. I tried such as:
`super.Some.p1`, `Some.super.p1`, `super@Some.p1`, `this@Some.p1`, none correct...

Comment: Property initializers in interface are not allowed, which version of Kotlin allows this?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I add the get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super` is not defined in the context of setting default value for constructor parameter. It's defined only inside the class body. So you may use the following workarounds:

**VARIANT 1**

Use auxilary nullable constructor parameters:

```kotlin
class SomeImpl(_p1: String? = null, _p2: String? = null) : Some {
    override val p1: String = _p1 ?: super.p1
    override val p2: String = _p2 ?: super.p2
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val someImpl0 = SomeImpl()
println("${someImpl0.p1}, ${someImpl0.p2}") //p1, p2
val someImpl1 = SomeImpl("1")
println("${someImpl1.p1}, ${someImpl1.p2}") //1, p2
val someImpl2 = SomeImpl("1", "2")
println("${someImpl2.p1}, ${someImpl2.p2}") //1, 2
```

**VARIANT 2**

You may move `p1` & `p2` interface parameters to companion object, so derived classes may use them as default values in constructor while hiding them:

```kotlin
interface Some {
    companion object {
        const val p1 = "p1"
        const val p2 = "p2"
    }
}

class SomeImpl(val p1: String = Some.p1, val p2: String = Some.p2) : Some
```

Usage is the same. BUT in this case (unlike in the first variant) properties will be unaccesible from instance if it will be casted to `Some`:

```kotlin
val someImpl : Some = SomeImpl()
println("${someImpl.p1}, ${someImpl.p2}") //Will not compile
```